# Exponent calculation in Azure Logic Apps or Power Automate

Tags: expression, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

How can I do an exponent expression in Azure Logic Apps or Power Automate. I can't find any Math functions in expression that can achieve this. For example int^int.

I have red the documentation, but it seems like there is not any function for this purpose.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#math-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `Azure logic app` does not support exponent expression directly. But you can use [Inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) to execute exponential calculations.

`Inline code` uses `JavaScript`, there are two syntaxes for you to execute exponential calculations：

**1.**

```
base ** power
```

**2.**

```
Math.pow(base , power)
```

The logic app workflow is like this:

[image]

**Note:**

`Azure logic app` needs [integration account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal).